# Books on Ukrainian War of Independence 1917-1921

Tags: war, independence, ukraine, 1920s, 1910s

I would like to know more about the period in the history of Ukraine between 1917 and 1921. Therefore, I am looking for a book that methodologically describes the events in the territory where Ukrainians lived from 1917 to 1921 and the neighboring territories.

Comment: Requests for reference suggestions are generally considered off-topic here. You might want to have a look at the corresponding [Wikipedia page's references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_War_of_Independence#References) as a starting point.

Comment: Wikipedia reference page does not contain such a book. So this is a reasonable question, but I suspect that the answer is negative. There are several good books on history of Ukraine, but none of those that I now gives a detailed description of this war, with chronology of all main events for all locations in Ukraine.

Comment: Ukrainian Wikipedia page has more references, in Ukrainian language, but still there is no book which looks like a comprehensive study of this period.